# Why Vegeta's energy wasnt able to reactivate Goku's Ultra Instinct but Uub's energy was?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, japanese-language, dragon-ball-manga

In chapter 66 of the Dragon Ball Super manga Vegeta's energy wasnt able to refill Goku of energy to reactivate his Ultra Instinct technique, but after receiving Uub's energy he was able to. Goku hints that it was because Uub's energy feels like the ki of a god, but Vegeta is also supposed to have god ki. Are Vegeta god ki and Uub "energy of a god" supposed to be different? Do they spell differently in the original japanese version?

Why Vegeta's energy wasnt able to reactivate Goku's Ultra Instinct but Uub's energy was?